# Functions to comment and uncomment multiple lines in ".ttl" file

Tags: vim

I am trying to write some functions in my `.vimrc` to comment and uncomment my code files. My program works successfully except with `.ttl` files.

The functions i use are the following:

```
 " Add comment and uncomment
map qq :call Comment()<CR>
map ww :call Uncomment()<CR>

function! Comment()
    let ft = &filetype
    if ft == 'php' || ft == 'ruby' || ft == 'sh' || ft == 'make' || ft == 'python' || ft == 'perl'
            silent s/^/\#/
    elseif ft == 'c' || ft == 'cpp' || ft == 'java' || ft == 'javascript' || ft == 'go'
            silent s:^:\/\/:g
    elseif ft == 'ttl'
            silent s/^/;//
    elseif ft == 'vim'
            silent s:^:\":g
    endif
endfunction

function! Uncomment()
    let ft = &filetype
    if ft == 'php' || ft == 'ruby' || ft == 'sh' || ft == 'make' || ft == 'python' || ft == 'perl'
            silent s/^\#//
    elseif ft == 'c' || ft == 'cpp' || ft == 'java' || ft == 'javascript' || ft == 'go'
            silent s:^\/\/::g
    elseif ft == 'ttl'
            silent s/^\;/
    elseif ft == 'vim'
            silent s:^\"::g
    endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last slash: `silent s/^/;/` and it will work. By the way, there are [lots](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) [of](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) [plugins](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim) that already do the same. However if you still want to write your own script, i'd suggest you to check `:he commentstring` and [use only nonrecursive mappings](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html), i.e. `nnoremap` instead of just `map`.

Comment: Hi Andy Rk, it's not worked scripts .vimrc. but when i open file abc.ttl :s/^/;/ is successfully. What something else?

Answer (score 0):

As Andy Rk mentionned it some plugins exists to do that: If you're not creating
 these functions for learning purpose, using the plugins would save you **a lot** 
 of work.

I personnaly use [NERDCommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter)
which is really good I think it is really worth a look:

- **The installation is really simple:** If you use a plugin manager you simply
  have to add a line in your `.vimrc`. (For example with [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug)
  just add `Plug 'godlygeek/tabular'` to your `.vimrc`, run `:PlugInstall` and voilà 
  it's ready to run).
- **A large number of filetype are supported**: The plugin works with 300+ types
  of files out of the box. Think to all to work that would save you.
- **The behavior is pretty sensible**: A lot of different actions are possible,
  for example with a `.c` file you can comment a selection in different ways,
  just visually select some line of code and see the result:
- <kbd>Leader</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

```c
/*int main()*/
/*{*/
    /*printf("Hello World");*/
    /*return 0;*/
/*}*/
```

- <kbd>Leader</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>

```c
/*int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}*/
```

- <kbd>Leader</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>

```c
/*
 *int main()
 *{
 *    printf("Hello World");
 *    return 0;
 *}
 */
```

A lot of other options are available as described in the
[README](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter/blob/master/README.md).

If your don't like visual selection you can also prefix use `[count]mapping` to
apply the action to the `[count]` lines after your cursor.

Also you can simply uncomment any commented line with
<kbd>Leader</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>.

Maybe you should give it a try and then see if you still need to write your custom functions.

Answer (score 0):

#### Standing on the shoulders of giants

I would highly recommend commenting plugin like [commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) (which I use), [Nerd Commenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter), [EnhCommentify](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=23), [tComment](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim), ..., [etc](http://vimawesome.com/?q=comment). There is no shame in using a plugin. Especially since comment toggling is deceptively more complicated than expected.

#### Customizing Commentary.vim

Simply set `'commentstring'` to your comment style for your filetype. Most often this is already setup for you if Vim recognizes your filetype. See `:h 'commentstring'`.

Example of changing `'commentstring'` for php. Add the following to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim`:

```
set commentstring=#\ %s
```

Note: I use commentary this may not work for other comment plugins. As always, read the documentation.

#### More information

```
:h 'commentstring'
:h :set
:h filetype
:h new-filetype
:h ftdetect
:h ftplugins
:h after-directory
```